# Recurrence solving in Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was doing the exercise and I got stuck -.-. This is the task I have to do.

[image]

The solution: I dont get the step of the yellow one. I tried to understand but I lack of the knowledge of the logarithm. Can you explaine
[image]

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Whatever the log basis is, you have `log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)` and consequently  `log(1/a) = -log(a)`

Comment: Thanks Damien for you explanation. But I still don't get it. 
2(n/2)log2 = log2(n)
log2(n/2)
log2(n/2) = -log2(n/2)
Because n/2 = its still will stay as it is.

Comment: `log(n/2) = log(n) - log(2)` . I don't understand what is unclear

Comment: @Sayuri Damien gave you everything to understand how to obtain the *yellow* line...

Comment: @Sayuri log2 is a function this log2(n/2) is the value of it at n/2. It is not log2 x n/2! Then from Damien's log2(n/2) is log2(n)-log2(2) and as 2(n/2)=n...

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation. I was confused but now I got the idea!

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that `log ab = log a + log b` also `log (1/a) = - log a`

So when you have `2(n/2) log(n/2)` you can write `log(n/2)` as `log(1/2 x n)` which using `log ab = log a + log b` equals `log(n) + log(1/2)`

`2(n/2) log(n/2) = 2(n/2) (log n + log(1/2)) = n(log n + log(1/2))`

Also `log (1/a) = - log a`, and hence `log(1/2) = - log 2`

That is how you get

`2(n/2) log(n/2) + n = 2(n/2) (log n + log(1/2)) + n = n(log n + log(1/2))`

`= n(log n - log 2 ) + n`

Since `log 2 = 1` in base 2 you will have `n(log n - log 2 ) + n =  n(log n - 1) + n = n lg n`